# specify parametric coefficients in gam (mgcv)

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I know it is possible to specify the smoothing parameters in a mgcv::gam() using the sp argument. Is there a way to specify the parametric coefficients in the same model?

For example, if I have

```
model1 <-gam(y~s(x1) + s(x2) + x3 + x4)
```

and I want to remove the parametric terms but retain the smoothing parameters of model1, I would:

```
model2<-gam(y~s(x1) + s(x2), sp = model1$sp)
```

How could I set up model3 such that the parametric coefficients from model1 are used in model3?

```
model3<-gam(y~s(x1) + s(x2) + x3, sp = model1$sp, ......)
```

The ultimate goal of is to be able to determine percent deviance explained by each variable.  So to find the deviance explained of  x1, the plan is to do:

```
model_minusx1<-gam(y~s(x2) + x3 + x4, sp=model1$sp[2])
```

The percent variance explained by x1 is thus

```
  (summary(model1)$dev.expl - summary(model_minusx1)$dev.expl)/summary(model1)$dev.expl
```

However, removing x1 could cause the coefficients of the parametric terms to change, especially if there is any correlation/concurvity between x1 and the parametric terms.  So ideally I'd like to keep the parametric coefficients constant as well.

Comment: What if you used `model2` to predict the `y` values in the data and then used the residuals as the response? Would that do what you need? Perhaps this is a better question for [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic.

Comment: I suppose you could multiple `x3` by the parametric coef for `x3` and then include this new term (not`x3` itself) in the model as and offset: `+ offset(new_x3)` as that will get a coef of 1 by definition, which is what you want. Note that if you showed simplified models in the Q and your realy models involve a link other than identity, then you need to put the offset on the link scale also.

Comment: @GavinSimpson is this what you had in mind:
`off<-coefficients(model1)[1]*x3 +
      coefficients(model1)[2] *x4`

`model_offset<-gam(y~s(x1) + s(x2), sp = model1$sp, offset = off)`
where model_offset is equivalent to model1?

I edited my original question to explain why I am asking this in the first place (calculating % variance explained by each variable) - and using `offset` did not appear to help, as the deviance explained of model_offset is very low and not at all equivalent to model1.

Comment: @webbe Yes, except I’d want to make sure that `coef(model)[2]` is the coefficients for `x3` and the same for the coef for `x4`. Then yes, you leave `x3` and `x4` out of the formula as they would enter via the offset.

Comment: I suspect that the offset is somewhat ignored in the deviance explained. Perhaps. Why do you want to know this in term of variance explained? If you fit `x3` and `x4` as smooths with `k = 2, fix = TRUE` (check that that gives 1 EDF linear terms) you could look at them in terms of variance components viola `gam.vcomp(model)` if you really want this in terms of variances.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, yes the offset seems to be completely ignored in deviance explained.  My response variable is change over time and I want to be able to say how much each explanatory variable contributed to that change over time.  For example, X1 contributed 10% while X2 contributed 50%.  The suggestion to change `model1` to `gam(y~s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3,k=2,fix=TRUE) + s(x4,k=2,fix=TRUE)` is a good one and I should be able to use this in determining the % variance explained, i.e.  `(summary(model1)$dev.expl - summary(model_minusx1)$dev.expl)/summary(model1)$dev.expl`